# How to modify the ChromeDriver settings during the execution of the program?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am now using Python + selenium + Chromedriver and I am trying to log in the my account automatically.

To make my program faster, here is my strategy:

1. Firstly, disable the picture-loading setting when initialling the driver.(see the code blow)
2. Since my log in process needs validation code, after fetching the page, I want to enable the picture-loading setting so that I can click the "refresh" button to gain validation code picture.

Here is my code for step 1:

```
ChromeOption = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
ChromeOption.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
Driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = './chromedriver', chrome_options = ChromeOption)
```

However, I don't know how to modify the driver settings. I search the document all day and found nothing.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter the chromedriver settings after it has been spun off because :

- It would mean that the existing chromedriver process needs to be killed and re-invoked with the new arguments, which would now mean that your test would need to be started off again.This would essentially mean that your test has to start off again from the first.